# Multiple \marginnote commands on the same line in math environment

Tags: marginpar, marginnote

If multiple `\marginnote` commands are triggered on the same line, by default they are typeset on top of one another, making them unreadable. I would like them to stack vertically, which is the default behaviour of `\marginpar`. It doesn't matter that some of them will therefore not be rendered immediately adjacent to the line in which they were generated.

I need this to work both in math environments and non-math environments, so I can't use `\marginpar` itself. And I have this all over the place, so it has to be automatic like marginpar; I can't manually adjust the vertical spacing of each one.

Comment: `\marginnote` has an optional argument for vertical offset: `\marginnote[<left>]{<right>}[<voffset>]`

Comment: Thanks. I have this all over the place so it has to be automatic, just like marginpar.

Comment: Do you want it to expand downward or in both directions?  BTW, a MWE would be nice.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I think can do this, but it will take some time.  In addition to not overlapping, I assume you don't want it going off the bottom of the page either.

Comment: If I get some time I will try to add an example. John: that sounds great; it wouldn't matter so much if it went off the bottom of the page, since I'm using it to visualize placement of index entries in a draft of a book, rather than for use in a production document.

Comment: I've run into a problem.  When I put \marginfill (my version of \marginpar) into a math display environment for testing, it gets called twice, which causes my indexes to be out of synch.  I need to figure out how to have it only called once.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I ran into the same double-call problem with the OP's former question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218095/supply-commands-to-be-executed-upon-leaving-math-mode/218106#218106.  I, too had to stumble on "an epiphany" to resolve it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: report]

It takes two runs for the margin notes to show up.  I put the content as well as the location into the aux file so that I didn't have to synch two different sources.

I used `\marginparpush` to separate consecutive margin notes vertically.  I added `\marginfillstyle` to set the font etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{abspage}
\AddEverypageHook{\marginfillpage}

\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

% user modifiable formatting
\newcommand{\marginfillstyle}{\raggedright\normalsize\normalfont\hspace{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\newcount\MF@index% global variables
\newcount\MF@total
\newlength{\MF@x}% marginpar offset
\newlength{\MF@y}% pagehook cursor location
\newlength{\MF@top}% marginpar area
\newlength{\MF@bottom}
\newlength{\MF@width}% \marginparwidth might get clobbered
\newlength{\MF@push}% \marginparpush might get clobbered
\newcount\MF@min% needed for nested loops
\newcount\MF@max
\newlength{\MF@adjust}
\newif\ifMF@repeat
\newif\ifMF@main

\newcommand{\marginfill}[1]% #1 = text for margin note
{\pdfsavepos
  \protected@write\@auxout{\let\theabspage=\relax}{\string\newmarginfill{\theabspage}%
    {\noexpand\number\pdflastypos}{#1}}%
}%

\newcommand{\newmarginfill}[3]% #1 = abspage, #2 = location, #3 = text
{\global\advance\MF@total by \@ne
  \expandafter\gdef\csname MF@page\the\MF@total\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname MF@location\the\MF@total\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname MF@note\the\MF@total\endcsname{#3}%
}%

\newcommand{\marginfillpage}% cursor 1in from top left corner
{\stepcounter{abspage}%
\ifodd\c@page
  \setlength{\MF@x}{\oddsidemargin}%
  \addtolength{\MF@x}{\textwidth}%
  \addtolength{\MF@x}{\marginparsep}%
\else
  \setlength{\MF@x}{\evensidemargin}%
  \addtolength{\MF@x}{-\marginparsep}%
  \addtolength{\MF@x}{-\marginparwidth}%
\fi
\setlength{\MF@y}{\paperheight}%
\addtolength{\MF@y}{-1in}%
\setlength{\MF@top}{\MF@y}%
\addtolength{\MF@top}{-\topmargin}%
\addtolength{\MF@top}{-\headheight}%
\addtolength{\MF@top}{-\headsep}%
\setlength{\MF@bottom}{\MF@top}%
\addtolength{\MF@bottom}{-\textheight}%
\setlength{\MF@width}{\marginparwidth}%
\setlength{\MF@push}{\marginparpush}%
% This algorithm overlays a lot of dimen registers, depending on how many notes are on the page.
% These registers will be restored by the \endgroup, but many will not be available until then.
% The \MF@...  dimens defined above should be safe.
\begingroup
\countdef\index=1
\index=0
\MF@repeattrue
\loop% locate all notes on this page
  \ifnum\MF@index<\MF@total
    \global\advance\MF@index by \@ne
    \edef\temp{\the\MF@index}%
    \@ifundefined{MF@page\temp}{}{%
    \ifnum\value{abspage}=\csname MF@page\temp\endcsname\relax
      \dimendef\yloc=\index
      \yloc=\csname MF@location\temp\endcsname sp\relax
      \savebox{\index}{\parbox[c]{\MF@width}%
        {\marginfillstyle \csname MF@note\temp\endcsname}}%
      \advance\index by \@ne
    \else
      \MF@repeatfalse
      \global\advance\MF@index by \m@ne
    \fi}%
  \else\MF@repeatfalse
  \fi
\ifMF@repeat \repeat
% are there any notes this page?
\ifnum\index>0 \MF@process\fi
\endgroup}

%***** moduals used by \marginfillpage *****

\newcommand{\MF@process}%
{\countdef\total=2
\countdef\min=3
\countdef\max=4
\total=\index
%create additional local length variables
\dimendef\tempdima=\index
\advance\index by \@ne
\dimendef\tempdimb=\index
\advance\index by \@ne
\dimendef\tempdimc=\index
% resolve overlaps
\MF@freespace{\tempdimb}%
\ifdim\tempdimb<1pt \MF@cram{\tempdimb}%
\else \MF@findsolution
\fi
% output notes to page
\index=0
\loop
  \dimendef\yloc=\index
  \MF@adjust=\yloc% in case \rlap or \raisebox clobbers \yloc
  \advance\MF@adjust by -\MF@y
  \rlap{\hspace{\MF@x}\raisebox{\MF@adjust}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox{\index}}}%
  \advance\index by \@ne
\ifnum\index<\total \repeat}

\newcommand{\MF@freespace}[1]% #1 = dimen to return total free space
{\let\freespace=#1%
\freespace=\MF@top
\advance \freespace by -\MF@bottom
\index=0
\loop% check for no solution
  \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\freespace by -\tempdima
  \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\freespace by -\tempdima
  \advance\freespace by -\MF@push
  \advance\index by \@ne
\ifnum\index<\total\relax \repeat
\advance\freespace by \MF@push}

\newcommand{\MF@cram}[1]% #1 = free space
{\let\top=#1%
\top=-0.5\top% center excess
\advance\top by \MF@top
\index=0
\loop% overlap top and bottom
  \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\top by -\tempdima
  \dimendef\yloc=\index
  \yloc=\top
  \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\top by -\tempdima
  \advance\top by -\MF@push
  \advance\index by \@ne
\ifnum\index<\total\relax \repeat}

\newcommand{\MF@findsolution}% main loop
{\min=0% start of middle
\max=\total% end of middle+1
\loop
  \MF@mainfalse
  \MF@addtotop
  \MF@addtobottom
  \ifMF@main\relax\else% wait until top and bottom done
    \MF@min=\min
    \MF@max=\max
    \advance\MF@max by \m@ne
    \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max \MF@locate\fi% find overlapping notes in middle
    \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max
      \MF@maintrue
      \MF@apply% cannot use nested loop
      \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max \MF@apply\fi
      \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max \MF@apply\fi
      \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max \MF@apply\fi
      \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max \MF@apply\fi
      \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max \MF@apply\fi
      \ifnum\MF@min<\MF@max
        \errormessage{Exceeded \string\marginfill algorithm capacity.}
      \fi
      \MF@apply
    \fi
  \fi
\ifMF@main \repeat}

\newcommand{\MF@addtotop}% resets \min and \ifMF@main
{\let\top=\tempdimb
\ifnum\min=0 \top=\MF@top
\else
  \index=\min
  \advance\index by \m@ne
  \dimendef\yloc=\index
  \top=\yloc
  \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\top by -\tempdima
  \advance\top by -\MF@push
\fi
\settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\min}}%
\advance\top by -\tempdima
\dimendef\yloc=\min
\ifdim\top<\yloc
  \yloc=\top
  \advance\min by \@ne
  \MF@maintrue
\fi}

\newcommand{\MF@addtobottom}% resets \max and \ifMF@main
{\let\bottom=\tempdimb
\ifnum\max=\total \bottom=\MF@bottom
\else
  \dimendef\yloc=\max
  \bottom=\yloc
  \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\max}}%
  \advance\bottom by \tempdima
  \advance\bottom by \MF@push
\fi
\index=\max
\advance\index by \m@ne
\settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
\advance\bottom by \tempdima
\dimendef\yloc=\index
\ifdim\bottom>\yloc
  \yloc=\bottom
  \max=\index
  \MF@maintrue
\fi}

\newcommand{\MF@locate}% returns \MF@min, \MF@max and \MF@adjust
{\begingroup% needed for nested loop
\let\top=\tempdimb
\let\test=\tempdimc
\let\size=\MF@adjust
\dimendef\yloc=\min
\top=\yloc
\settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\min}}%
\advance\top by -\tempdima
\advance\top by -\MF@push
%
\size=0pt
\index=\min
\loop% find largest overlap
  \advance\index by \@ne
  \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance \top by -\tempdima
  \dimendef\yloc=\index
  \test=\yloc
  \advance\test by -\top
  \ifdim\test>\size \size=\test
    \MF@min=\index
  \fi
  \top=\yloc
  \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\top by -\tempdima
  \advance\top by -\MF@push
\ifnum\index<\MF@max \repeat% \MF@max = \max-1
\MF@max=\MF@min
\ifdim\size>1pt
  \advance\MF@min by \m@ne
  \MF@expand% find all contiguous overlaps
  \MF@average% returns \MF@adjust
\fi
\global\MF@min=\MF@min
\global\MF@max=\MF@max
\global\MF@adjust=\MF@adjust
\endgroup}

\newcommand{\MF@expand}% locate all contiguous margin notes
{\let\test=\tempdimb
\dimendef\yloc=\MF@min
\test=\yloc
\advance\test by 0.5\size% add correction
\loop
  \MF@repeatfalse
  \ifnum\MF@min > \min
    \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\MF@min}}%
    \advance\test by \tempdima
    \advance\test by \MF@push
    \advance\MF@min by \m@ne
    \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\MF@min}}%
    \advance\test by \tempdima
    \dimendef\yloc=\MF@min
    \ifdim\yloc>\test \advance\MF@min by \@ne
    \else\MF@repeattrue
    \fi
  \fi
\ifMF@repeat \repeat
%
\dimendef\yloc=\MF@max
\test=\yloc
\advance\test by -0.5\size% add correction
\loop
  \MF@repeatfalse
  \ifnum\MF@max>\max\relax\else
    \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\MF@max}}%
    \advance\test by -\tempdima
    \advance\test by -\MF@push
    \advance\MF@max by \@ne
    \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\MF@max}}%
    \advance\test by -\tempdima
    \dimendef\yloc=\MF@max
    \ifdim\yloc<\test \advance\MF@max by \m@ne
    \else\MF@repeattrue
    \fi
  \fi
\ifMF@repeat \repeat}

\newcommand{\MF@average}% returns \MF@adjust
{\let\offset=\tempdimb
\offset=0pt
\MF@adjust=0pt
\index=\MF@min
\loop
  \settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\offset by \tempdima
  \advance\MF@adjust by \offset
  \dimendef\yloc=\index
  \advance\MF@adjust by \yloc
  \settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\index}}%
  \advance\offset by \tempdima
  \advance\offset by \MF@push
  \advance\index by \@ne
\ifnum\index>\MF@max\relax\else \repeat
\advance\index by -\MF@min
\divide\MF@adjust by \index}

\newcommand{\MF@apply}% corrects one margin note at a time
{\settoheight{\tempdima}{\usebox{\MF@min}}%
\advance\MF@adjust by -\tempdima
\dimendef\yloc=\MF@min
\yloc=\MF@adjust
\settodepth{\tempdima}{\usebox{\MF@min}}%
\advance\MF@adjust by -\tempdima
\advance\MF@adjust by -\MF@push
\advance\MF@min by \@ne}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
First line \marginfill{First note.}%
with not enough room. \marginfill{Second note}

\vfill
Isolated group in display style
\begin{align}
x &= a &\marginfill{Third note is a longer note.}\\
y &= b &\marginfill{Fourth note is a longer note.}
\end{align}

\vfill
Last line \marginfill{Fifth note.}%
with not enough room. \marginfill{Sixth note.}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\newpage
First line in text area \marginfill{text area}
\begin{figure}[t]
\marginfill{float}
\centering\rule{.5in}{.5in}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: test]

Comment: Thanks for this nice analysis! I typically have 2 or 3 margin notes declared on the same line, so the unconstrained approach would definitely not be sufficient (and anyway that's what `\marginnote` allows already.)

Comment: I am still debugging my code, but am very close.  However, I have been spending way too much time on this and will not return to the project until after Xmas.

Comment: Okay, it's done.  I had an epiphany and had to try it out.

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing (+1). Are you aware of any bugs/limitations? If this is reliable it could be a package (and I would use it)!

Comment: No bugs that I know of, but I keep wanting to redo the whole thing using global macros instead of local registers.

Comment: Did you ever get around to revisiting this code, @JohnKormylo? For documents with many marginnotes, your code above enters an infinite loop for me, then runs out of memory. However, I have no idea how to debug it.