# Supply commands to be executed upon leaving math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have an important macro `\textmacro` that can only be invoked in text mode. I would like a macro `\mathmacro` such that issuing the command

```
Some text $a^b\mathmacro c^d$ more text
```

is automatically transformed and evaluates as follows:

```
Some text $a^b c^d$\textmacro more text
```

That is, the macro position is 'moved' to just after the end of math mode, at which point `\textmacro` is called. Is there any internal LaTeX technology that would allow this? I would need this to work in `$...$`, `equation` and `align` environments.

*Edit*: the `\textmacro` command puts a note in the margin using `\marginpar`. There is no comparable command that operates the same way in both text mode and math mode; in particular, `\marginnote` does not stack comments vertically.

*Edit*: just to make things a bit harder/more realistic: (1) the `\textmacro` commands will sometimes be inside `\ensuremath` commands, so e.g. `$a^b \ensuremath{x \mathmacro y}$` should expand to `$a^b \ensuremath{x y}$\textmacro`. (2) In general there will be multiple invocations of `\mathmacro` inside the math environment, and they must all get pushed to the end. (3) When used in text mode, `\mathmacro` should just behave like `\textmacro`. (4) In general `\mathmacro` will take an argument.

Comment: The first option (within `$..$`) is easy: `\newcommand{\textmacro}{abc}
\def\mathmacro#1${#1$\textmacro}` The others aren't. What is this "important macro" that can only be invoked in text mode? Using `\mbox` initiates text mode. Shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: The `\textmacro` command puts a note in the margin using `\marginpar`. For more context see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Werner's comment for the `$...$` form, but added forms that work for `equation` and `align`.

EDITED to handle the OP's requirements:

1) arguments to `\mathmacro`;

2) multiple calls to `\mathmacro` in a single environment;

3) works when embedded within `\ensuremath` argument.

REVISED SOLUTION (can handle multiple `\mathmacro` calls)

In this approach, to allow for multiple calls, I use `\mathmacro` to build a semicolon separated list (disallows the `;` therefore in your `\marginpar`s, but you can manually change the separator) of the `\mathmacro` arguments.

Then, upon completion of the environment, I call on a routine to parse that list, and issue a `\textmacro` call to `\marginpar` for each argument in the list.  Along the way, I had to handle a quirk of `align` which makes a double pass, originally resulting in doubled calls to `\mathmacro`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\textmacro[1]{\marginpar{\textbf{\sffamily #1}}}
% FIX FOR $...$ PER WERNER'S USAGE
\def\mathmacro#1#2${#2$\textmacro{#1}}
\makeatletter
% FIX FOR EQUATION
\let\svequation\equation
\let\svendequation\endequation
\def\eqfinishmacro{\expandafter\eqfinishhelpA\eqfinishdata\relax;\relax}
\def\eqfinishhelpA#1;#2\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#1\else\textmacro{#1}\if\relax#2\relax\else\eqfinishhelpA#2\relax\fi\fi%
  \@gobble}
\def\eqfinishdata{}
\newcommand\equationmacro[1]{%
  \xdef\eqfinishdata{\eqfinishdata#1;}}
\def\equation{\let\mathmacro\equationmacro\svequation}
\def\endequation{\svendequation\eqfinishmacro\gdef\eqfinishdata{}}
% FIX FOR ALIGN
\let\svalign\align
\let\svendalign\endalign
\def\alfinishmacro{\expandafter\alfinishhelpA\alfinishdata\relax;\relax}
\def\alfinishhelpA#1;#2\relax{%
  \ifx\relax#1\else\textmacro{#1}\if\relax#2\relax\else\alfinishhelpA#2\relax\fi\fi%
  \@gobble}
\def\alfinishdata{}
\newcommand\alignmacro[1]{%
  \xdef\alfinishdata{\alfinishdata#1;}}
\def\align{\let\mathmacro\alignmacro\svalign\def\alfinishdata{}}
\def\endalign{\svendalign\alfinishmacro\gdef\alfinishdata{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Some text $a^b\mathmacro{MP} c^d$ more text\par
Some more text without a macro $a^b c^d$ more text\par
An equation using mathmacro
\begin{equation}
  a^b\mathmacro{EQ XYZ} c^d
\end{equation}%
to see if it works.\par
An equation using mathmacro
\begin{equation}
  a^b\mathmacro{EQ ARG.} c^d\mathmacro{2nd eq test}
\end{equation}%
to see if it works.\par
Here we have an equation without the mathmacro
\begin{equation}
  a^b =c^d
\end{equation}
but some following text.\par
Align with the mathmacro
\begin{align}
  a^b \mathmacro{AL ARG.} &= c^d &x &= y\mathmacro{2nd test}\\
  A^B \mathmacro{3rd test} &= C^D & X &= y
\end{align}%
to also see if it works.\par
Here we us align without the mathmacro
\begin{align}
  a^b &= c^d
\end{align}
but some following text.\par
Some text $a^b\mathmacro{ABC} c^d$ more text to see if original definition active.
\end{document}
```

[image]

ORIGINAL SOLUTION (allows only one `\mathmacro` call per environment)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\textmacro}[1][ABC]{\marginpar{\textbf{\sffamily #1}}}
% FIX FOR $...$ PER WERNER'S USAGE
\def\mathmacro#1#2${#2$\textmacro[#1]}
% FIX FOR EQUATION
\let\svequation\equation
\let\svendequation\endequation
\def\eqfinishmacro{}
\newcommand\equationmacro[1]{\gdef\eqfinishmacro{\textmacro[#1]}}
\def\equation{\let\mathmacro\equationmacro\svequation}
\def\endequation{\svendequation\eqfinishmacro\gdef\eqfinishmacro{}}
% FIX FOR ALIGN
\let\svalign\align
\let\svendalign\endalign
\def\alfinishmacro{}
\newcommand\alignmacro[1]{\gdef\alfinishmacro{\textmacro[#1]}}
\def\align{\let\mathmacro\alignmacro\svalign}
\def\endalign{\svendalign\alfinishmacro\gdef\alfinishmacro{}}
\begin{document}
Some text $a^b\mathmacro{MP} c^d$ more text\par
Some more text without a macro $a^b c^d$ more text\par
An equation using mathmacro
\begin{equation}
  a^b\mathmacro{EQ ARG.} c^d%\mathmacro
\end{equation}
to see if it works.\par
Here we have an equation without the mathmacro
\begin{equation}
  a^b =c^d
\end{equation}
Align with the mathmacro
\begin{align}
  a^b \mathmacro{AL ARG.} &= c^d
\end{align}
to also see if it works.\par
Here we us align without the mathmacro.
\begin{align}
  a^b &= c^d
\end{align}
Some text $a^b\mathmacro{ABC} c^d$ more text to see if original definition active.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for this nice answer. How about multiple invocations of $\mathmacro$ in the same math environment? I would need them all to be pushed to the end. Also, I need to handle `\ensuremath` in general...

Comment: I have added these requirements to the question.

Comment: @JamieVicary  That is a bit tougher, but I'll give it some thought.

Comment: Is it possible to write a macro that saves every `\mathmacro` call by concatenating it to a big request string? Then once we leave math mode with `\end{equation}`, `\end{align}` or `$`, we could simply execute that big concatenated macro.

Comment: @JamieVicary  That would be indeed be the approach.  The typical way I do that expands the contents, which of course one can't do in math mode with a `\marginpar`.  So I have to think harder.

Comment: @JamieVicary  Please see revision, which can now handle multiple calls to `\mathmacro` in an environment.

Comment: Looks great Steven. What do you think about the `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @JamieVicary `\ensuremath` appears not be a problem for `$...$`, `equation` and `align`,   and all forms handle multiple invocations of `\mathmacro`, best I can tell.  For example, `$\mathmacro{XYZ} a^b \ensuremath{x \mathmacro{CVB} y}$` works fine.