# Allowing some notes to float around using scrlayer-notecolumn

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-notecolumn

I am using KOMA script's scrlayer-notecolumn package to typeset margin notes.

I roughly have two kinds of notes I use.
I've maked them by giving them seperate commands in the MWE

- `\notethat`s for short quick notes, eg a definition of something in the text.
- `\aside`s which tend to expose on some side-topic.

It is desirable that the  `\notethat`s stay as close as possible to where they are declared.
Where-as the  `\aside`s can really be anyway in the rough area.
i.e. it is reasonable to swap the order of the notes around so as to keep the `\notethat`s near to where they were declared.
It is also reasonable to move `\aside`s more broadly, eg placing them before they were declared. To a lesser extent this is also true for `\notethat`s, in that they could be placed a few lines further up to accommodate an `\aside` that was too big.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\notethat}{\makenote{#1}}
\newcommand{\aside}{\makenote{#1}}

\section{Section 1.10.33 1914 translation by H. Rackham}

On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. 
\aside{Because I want exact positioning, for this demonstration, I am manually entering the blind text. sourcing from \texttt{lipsum.com} \bigskip}
These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is \textbf{untrammelled}
\notethat{\emph{Untrammelled} is not a common word}
and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Reordering etc. is not provided by `scrlayer-notecolumn`. First of all you would have to specify and implement a reordering algorithm. I think, you would also need additional information in the `slnc` files `scrlayer-notecolumn` uses to store the notes.

Comment: Your question writes in several places \notethat when you mean \aside. (I don't like this type of layout, to many footnotes are already distracting enough, to many notes on the side are a pain to read).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I on the other hand love footnotes and marginalia (and bits in brackets), both as a reader (some of the most interesting bits) -- and as a writer I always find that a linear structure is too constraining, but stick to it because normally I don't have the freedom to go wild like I do in this work. I guess it is a matter of taste, and my taste may differ from most, but this time I am out to please myself.

Comment: I'm always reading linear. I can't avoid this. I have to read first one sentence and then the next. I'm not able to read two or more texts in parallel. A writer who "goes wild" forces me constantly to decide which part I should read now and this disrupts my reception of the content of the text. Too many  (side/foot)notes (and links to other places) has for me the meaning that the writer is inable to arrange the content a logically way. It is for me a sign of incompetence.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment/216037?s=3|1.5738#216037