# Margin notes that can both stack and be used in floats/footnotes

Tags: floats, positioning, footnotes, marginpar, marginnote

`\marginpar` notes won’t overlap; if you add two notes close to one another, the second note will start below the first.  However, they can’t be used in floats or footnotes &c.

`\marginnote`s can be used anywhere, but when they’re close, they overlap and overwrite one another.

Is there a way to have side notes in floats and footnotes like `\marginnote`, but at the same time have them stack automatically like `marginpar`?

Comment: Yes, but it is not easy.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment