# How to shift up todonotes

Tags: todonotes

When i write many sidenotes on the same page, if there's no space, latex puts it over the bottom of page).
There's a simple method to overcome this issue? THX A LOT[image]

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr,float,graphicx}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[color=white,linecolor=black,textsize=footnotesize,textwidth=5cm, tickmarkheight=3mm]{todonotes}
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=70mm, marginparwidth=50mm,marginparsep=8mm]{geometry}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=black,bookmarksdepth=3, urlcolor=black}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\hyperlink{toc}{\textcolor{violet!50!blue}{Torna all'indice}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


    \title{Polymer science and engineering}
    \author{Francesco Soldi}
    \date{Academic year 2020/21}


    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
    \tableofcontents{}
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsubsection{Proprietà termiche}
    La \textit{Funzionalità} $f$ è il numero di legami che un qualsiasi monomero forma dopo il processo di polimerizzazione.
    Quando $f=2$ il polimero risultante sarà lineare, mentre non appena come $f \geq 3$ il 
    polimero sarà ramificato o addirittura costituito da una rete tridimensionale.
    Questo perché le catene lineari interagiscono tra loro attraverso legami di tipo fisico, che sono solitamente deboli e sono la causa del basso punto di fusione in questo tipo di strutture. 
    I polimeri a struttura reticolata, invece, interagiscono tramite legami \textit{covalenti} molto più forti e non sono in grado di fluire l'uno sull'altro.
    \todo{Questo è il motivo per cui il vetro, o le rocce, "fondono" a temperature molto alte, mentre molti polimeri lineari fondono a temperature molto più basse.}
    Altresì detto, la parte amorfa di un materiale polimerico è caratterizzata da una temperatura di transizione vetrosa.
    Questa è una transizione isofasica. 
    Al di sotto di questa temperatura i moti browniani tendono a congelarsi e la sostanza assume le caratteristiche meccaniche di un vetro, ossia è rigida, fragile e perde ogni caratteristica di plasticità.
    Al di sopra di questa temperatura i movimenti delle catene molecolari si riattivano e portano la macromolecola a divenire flessibile e gommosa.
    \todo{La rigidità è direttamente proporzionale al grado di cristallinità: più è alto, più il materiale è duro e termicamente stabile, ma al contempo è anche più fragile.}
    Le regioni cristalline sono invece caratterizzate da una temperatura di fusione $T_m$.
    Al di sopra della $T_m$ il polimero passa da uno stato solido ordinato cristallino a uno stato fuso (liquido viscoso), per cui il materiale perde ogni proprietà meccanica.
    \todo{Per un polimero amorfo questo passaggio è graduale e non c'è una vera e propria temperatura di melting, per questo lo stato "fuso" perde significato.
    La rottura dei legami potrebbe consentire il movimento indipendente, il materiale si decomporrebbe prima di fondersi.
    E un altra lunghissima nota dove non so più che cosa scrivere ma insomma devo scrivere qualcosa e allora che so boh cito la fanelli
    che è pure bona madò che spettacolo è pure simpatica, che poi oggi tutte so così stinfie, come se ce l'avessero solo loro ma insomma qualcosa ho scritto e niente la nota è andata fino in fondo alla pagina mannaggia}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Not that I can find in the manual.  marginnotes can be shifted.

Comment: how? i searched on the package documentation

Comment: Use voffset in `\marginnote[left]{right}[voffset]`

Comment: Going through the source code, it appears that \todo uses `\marginpar` in `\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine` so you could either replace `\marginpar` or edit `\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine` to use something else.  However, packing items into the margin is not an easy task (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment)

Comment: I had complete forgotten about the marginfix package.  See \mparshift (page 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use `\raisebox` inside `\marginpar`, but once the depth becomes negative, `\marginpar` gets confused.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,float,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[color=white,linecolor=black,textsize=footnotesize,textwidth=5cm, tickmarkheight=3mm]{todonotes}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=70mm, marginparwidth=50mm,marginparsep=8mm]{geometry}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, anchorcolor=black, citecolor=black,bookmarksdepth=3, urlcolor=black}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\hyperlink{toc}{\textcolor{violet!50!blue}{Torna all'indice}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\marginshift}
\setlength{\marginshift}{0pt}
\newsavebox{\leftmarginbox}
\newsavebox{\rightmarginbox}

\newcommand{\shiftedmarginpar}[2][]{%
  \savebox\leftmarginbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{#1}}%
  \savebox\rightmarginbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{#2}}%
  \ifvoid\leftmarginbox\else \ifdim\marginshift>\dp\leftmarginbox \marginshift=\dp\leftmarginbox\fi\fi
  \ifvoid\rightmarginbox\else \ifdim\marginshift>\dp\rightmarginbox \marginshift=\dp\rightmarginbox\fi\fi
  \marginpar[\ifvoid\leftmarginbox\else \raisebox{\marginshift}{\usebox\leftmarginbox}\fi]%
    {\ifvoid\rightmarginbox\else \raisebox{\marginshift}{\usebox\rightmarginbox}\fi}%
  \setlength{\marginshift}{0pt}}
  
\makeatletter
 \patchcmd{\@todonotes@drawMarginNoteWithLine}{\marginpar}{\shiftedmarginpar}{}{failed}
\makeatother

\title{Polymer science and engineering}
\author{Francesco Soldi}
\date{Academic year 2020/21}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
\tableofcontents{}
\section{Introduction}
\subsubsection{Proprietà termiche}
La \textit{Funzionalità} $f$ è il numero di legami che un qualsiasi monomero forma dopo il processo di polimerizzazione.
Quando $f=2$ il polimero risultante sarà lineare, mentre non appena come $f \geq 3$ il 
polimero sarà ramificato o addirittura costituito da una rete tridimensionale.
Questo perché le catene lineari interagiscono tra loro attraverso legami di tipo fisico, che sono solitamente deboli e sono la causa del basso punto di fusione in questo tipo di strutture. 
I polimeri a struttura reticolata, invece, interagiscono tramite legami \textit{covalenti} molto più forti e non sono in grado di fluire l'uno sull'altro.
\todo{Questo è il motivo per cui il vetro, o le rocce, "fondono" a temperature molto alte, mentre molti polimeri lineari fondono a temperature molto più basse.}
Altresì detto, la parte amorfa di un materiale polimerico è caratterizzata da una temperatura di transizione vetrosa.
Questa è una transizione isofasica. 
Al di sotto di questa temperatura i moti browniani tendono a congelarsi e la sostanza assume le caratteristiche meccaniche di un vetro, ossia è rigida, fragile e perde ogni caratteristica di plasticità.
Al di sopra di questa temperatura i movimenti delle catene molecolari si riattivano e portano la macromolecola a divenire flessibile e gommosa.
\setlength{\marginshift}{2cm}%
\todo{La rigidità è direttamente proporzionale al grado di cristallinità: più è alto, più il materiale è duro e termicamente stabile, ma al contempo è anche più fragile.}
Le regioni cristalline sono invece caratterizzate da una temperatura di fusione $T_m$.
Al di sopra della $T_m$ il polimero passa da uno stato solido ordinato cristallino a uno stato fuso (liquido viscoso), per cui il materiale perde ogni proprietà meccanica.
\todo{Per un polimero amorfo questo passaggio è graduale e non c'è una vera e propria temperatura di melting, per questo lo stato "fuso" perde significato.
La rottura dei legami potrebbe consentire il movimento indipendente, il materiale si decomporrebbe prima di fondersi.
E un altra lunghissima nota dove non so più che cosa scrivere ma insomma devo scrivere qualcosa e allora che so boh cito la fanelli
che è pure bona madò che spettacolo è pure simpatica, che poi oggi tutte so così stinfie, come se ce l'avessero solo loro ma insomma qualcosa ho scritto e niente la nota è andata fino in fondo alla pagina mannaggia}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! it work pretty well :)

Comment: While an interesting exercise, the marginfix package does a better job.